# How to add icons/images to the select's option in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, icons, dropdown, html-select

Assume this is my dropdown, then how can I add images to the options??

```
<select label="gender" value="male">
<option value={"male"}>male</option>
<option value={"female"}>female</option>
<option value={"others"}>others</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like html css do
Using “data-icon” attribute we can add any glyphicon icons to an option or optgroup

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-icon="glyphicon-music">Option1</option>
  <option data-icon="glyphicon-star">Option2</option>
  <option data-icon="glyphicon-glass">Option3</option>
</select>
```

from [thewebfosters](http://thewebfosters.com/add-icons-html-select-options/)

Comment: Thank you, for answering my question. but how can we add images??